# Karate - Not able to establish connection with pkcs12 keystore and password

Tags: karate

I am not able to establish connection with pkcs12 keystore and password. I have a crt certificate and key file for the same. Converted the same to PFX using openssl and followed the instructions as per the link https://github.com/intuit/karate#x509-certificate-authentication. Still facing timeout issues. I try with crt and key file in postman settings, it does work.

```
* configure ssl = { keyStore: 'classpath:sdfnon-prod.pfx', keyStorePassword: '*****', keyStoreType: 'pkcs12' }
```

Can you please suggest me, if there is something else that needs to be configured.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely a proxy is involved, please see these answers: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bkarate%5D+ssl+proxy

Answer (score 0):

I experienced a similar issue until a figured that the line

```
* configure ssl = { trustAll: true }
```

should go above the

```
* configure ssl = {...}
```

line in a feature file

Is interesting to me that adding the ssl info into the karate-config.js didn't need the trustAll flag set